# How to hook into Mantle

Tags: dictionary, hook, github-mantle

I'm using [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) and it fits my basic need. After declaring `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` and some `PropertyJSONTransformer`, I can turn a JSON Dictionary to an object

```
ETPUser *user = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ETPUser class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonDict error:nil];
```

Now I want to hook into this transformation process to do my other complex fields (setting other properties that are not declared in `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey`) in the `jsonDict`, but can't find any ways to do this

How to hook into Mantle ?

Comment: So you want to set default values when your user model is initialised?

Comment: @DavidCaunt I want to do additional steps for other properties beside the properties that I declare in JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064204/how-to-set-default-value-in-ios-mantle-model-subclass/23245115#23245115) help?

Comment: @DavidCaunt Look at the **dictionaryValue** in initWithDictionary, it is a **simplified** dictionary (only contains keys declared in JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey), but the original dictionary (got from server API endpoint) contains more keys than that

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what it is that you're trying to do. Please post some example JSON, the code for ETPUser, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this snippet:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

    NSDictionary *hookedValue = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"defaultValue1", @"defaultKey1",
                                @"defaultValue2", @"defaultKey2",
                                @"defaultValue3", @"defaultKey3",
                                nil];

    dictionary = [hookedValue mtl_dictionaryByAddingEntriesFromDictionary:dictionary];
    return [super initWithDictionary:dictionary error:error];
}
```